# production dockerfile with turbo repo , angular , nestJS

Tags: angular, docker-compose, dockerfile, nestjs, turborepo

Im trying to make a dockerfile for production with the technologie Turbo-repo (repository manager)Angular(Front-End) NestJS(back-end). [this is the architecture of the project.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1x0L.png)

I have try to adapt my dockerfile for dev mode but i need to use an nginx serv for angular to activate Https corrrectly . i have tried to make tow different dockerfile and build the image of this but i don't arrived to build then because the commande "npm install" can't download all the dependancies for the back or front project .